# Article reading application - WebView or TextView?

Tags: android, performance, webview, textview, article

I am trying to create a reader-type application for a particular website, so reading experience is essential. Of course I want to preserve article formatting as author inteded (via basic html tags (p, br, img) - no CSS so far).

The problem is that I am having hell of a time displaying this in a textview  the way I want with Html.fromHtml method. And dont even get me started on images, theyre all over the place.

Ive always been taught that webview is a no-no for native experience and its performance sucks, but then I learnt that Google Currents app uses it, and it even allows text justification, which is always nice for reading.

So .. what would you do? Hack that TextView into behaving or stick with WebView? Would it be so bad? Is there a way to figure out what the popular reading apps like The Verge are using?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I wrote the BGR app, among others, and I think you should go web view. I personally think that its a bad choice when people use it for a whole app, or to do the work that an app should be doing, but web views exist for formatting, so use it.

Comment: Ive checked out your app, peformance seems really good, any tips & tricks on webview performance?

Comment: The only trick, really, is that I load the content locally.  It's fed by an RSS feed, so I have model objects that include things like title and byline, but the content they send me is styled with html.  I build an html string from this with css in the head, etc. and then use `content.loadDataWithBaseURL("http://bgr.com/", html, "text/html", "UTF-8", "");` to load it.  That may be where the performance comes from.